# PHP countdown, need it dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, function, time, countdown

I have a PHP-script that adds time into a SQL-DB like this:

```
    $howlong = 75; // Amount of seconds 
    $timetowait=time()+ $howlong; // This inserts into "timetowait" in SQL DB
```

Then to show my users how long they have to wait, I have this:

```
$timeleft= $rows['timetowait']; // This is the field in DB from above^
func_time($timeleft); // Function below, which shows the time left
```

The function above is:

```
function func_time($until){
$now = time();
$difference = $until - $now;
$seconds = $difference;
$output = "$seconds seconds";
return $output;
}
```

It works fine, but I want it to be a dynamic countdown. (Automaticly counting down, without refreshing the site) My problem here, is that I am using the "time()", and not pure text (f.ex 21/11/2013 20:00)

Comment: you added a tag "javascript" in your question, so you are n the right path. You can find lot of tutorial on it based on the Date() javascript object. I suggest you to edit your question to add some html and js code you tried.

Comment: You can make a script on the client site using javascript, and sync it with the server, so it will be impossible to bypass it. (It will be checked when the time will get to zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this type of "countdown" like thing is handled by Javascript:

On the **client** side you *could* do something like this:

```
function countdown(seconds) {
    if(seconds > 0) {
        alert(seconds + ' Seconds Left');
        setTimeout(function(){
            countdown(--seconds);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        alert('Time out!');
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/fn4MV/

Comment: I want to use "return $output;" instead of an alert-box. How do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: I am sure you can figure it out :-) I am giving you a stepping stone.

Comment: I can't figure it out.. Tried a lot of stuff now.

Comment: @qwertynl I can see that the script works at jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work at my own site. How am I supposed to insert it into my PHP file?

Comment: @Marius this has nothing to do with PHP... This is a javascript script.

Comment: Again @melc ... Where is there any recursion in this example? You answer has just as much "recursion" and much more unstable (using `setInterval`)

Comment: @qwertynl to be honest i hoped for a constructive discussion that would also assist other visitors, but in no case compare our answers. I probably failed and i'm sorry if i caused anger. Also `setInterval` is not recursively called, it is repeatedly called which is less memory consuming i think.

Comment: I was just pointing out that you have errors and inconsistencies in your answer. And I usually use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` because the latter can cause headaches...

Comment: @qwertynl I understand that, and now It seems to be right. But it does not count down, even tho' Im now using the timeleft numbers, inside the script. Currently using "$output = "$seconds";
  return $output;"

Answer (score 0):

It is better to handle this on client side using javascript.

For example a count down per user could be as follows,

**js**

```
function printData(data){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerText=data;
}

var timeInSecs = Date.now()/(1000*60);
var howLong = 75;
var untilTimeInSecs = timeInSecs+howLong;
var countDownInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var timeLeft = untilTimeInSecs-timeInSecs;    
    printData(timeLeft);
    untilTimeInSecs--;

    if(timeLeft<=0){
        clearInterval(countDownInterval);
    }

},1000);
```

**html**

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zvsyu/2/

Comment: Your `timeInSecs` variable does not do anything and is pointless since you subtract it out anyway....

Comment: @qwertynl just added this to assist our friend here see the similarities with his code. The answer posted is a quick example of how this countdown could be achieved.

Answer (score -1):

You need javascript, if you have the number of second for the countdown, You only need a setInterval:

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp